# Calculating "next business day" with a time-of-day cutoff

Tags: php

I am trying to create a delivery time estimator where based on the day it is today, it will show how many days it will take to receive an item.

Everything is working great with this. The last part I am stuck on is how to set the date so that every day at 2 PM Pacific Time, it will change the date to the next day.

Right now, I have it set up to use Pacific Time. It is simply a matter of getting the date to change at the order cutoff time of 2 PM PST to the next day.

I thought about simply changing the timezone, but wasn't sure if factoring for daylight savings time would be an issue to consider with that approach.

I have added the code that is being used below:

```
<?php
if ((strlen(ini_get('date.timezone')) < 1) && function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
}

function getNextMondayDate($date) {
    $day = date('w', $date);
    if ($day==0) {
        $ret = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
    } else if ($day==6) {
        $ret = strtotime("+2 day", $date);
    } else {
        $ret = strtotime("now", $date);
    }
    return $ret;
}

function businessDays($days, $time) {       
    for ($i=0; $i<$days; $i++) {
        $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
        $day = date('w',$time);
        if ($day==0) {
            $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
        } else if ($day==6) {
            $time = strtotime('+2 day', $time);
        }
    }
    return $time;
}

$date =  date("l, F jS");
$dateStart = getNextMondayDate(strtotime("now"));

  if (date('w')==6 || date('w')==0){
// If the order is placed on Saturday or Sunday...
// THe numbers you see below are measured in days.  In the example below
// The delivery times for standard shipping are from 2-4 days from today
    $dateStandardMinMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(2,$dateStart)));
    $dateStandardMaxMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(4,$dateStart)));
    $dateExpressMinMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(0,$dateStart)));
    $dateExpressMaxMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(1,$dateStart)));
}else{
// Otherwise, use these estimates
    $dateStandardMinMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(3,$dateStart)));
    $dateStandardMaxMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(5,$dateStart)));
    $dateExpressMinMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(1,$dateStart)));
    $dateExpressMaxMG = date("l, F jS",getNextMondayDate(businessDays(2,$dateStart)));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Even if it's not too severe, you should look into [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The function `businessDays` doen't do anything in the script for instance and could essentially be deleted from your provided code as it is now.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message! There is one more portion of the code where dates (like today + 4) are created by adding to the values generated by my included code, and that's where the businessDays function is used. I did not include that portion as it didn't involve my original question, and did not want to add unnecessary code. Should I add it as well?

Comment: You should rather delete it if it's not relevant to the question. In order for people to be able to help you it's suitable to have as little code as possibly needed to reproduce the problem (or undesired result in this case), since it's much easier for people to comprehend and read the code then.

Comment: Thank you for this, I did decide to add the rest of the code for more clarification based on another response to this question I received.

Comment: `function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')` that function has existed for over a decade now, I think you're safe to skip the check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for a function to return the next business day that is a certain number of days from the current day – unless it's on a weekend or after 2PM in which case you want the next business day that's a certain number of days from the following business day? This should do that. I kept it all pretty sprawled out so it should be clear to understand.

```
function getDeliveryDay(int $days, int $date = null):int {
    if ($date === null) {
        $date = time();
    }
    $base = "now";
    if (date("H", $date) >= 14) {
        // if it's late, calculate from tomorrow
        $days++;
    }
    if (in_array(date("w", $date), [0, 6])) {
        // if it's a weekend, calculate from monday
        $base = "next monday";
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++) {
        // make sure delivery day isn't Saturday or Sunday
        // don't count those days in processing time either
        $result = strtotime("$base +$i days", $date);
        $w = date("w", $result);
        if (in_array($w, [0, 6])) $days++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Testing (at 3:00 on Thursday):

```
echo date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(0)) . "\n"; // should be Friday
echo date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(1)) . "\n"; // should be Monday
echo date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(2)) . "\n"; // should be Tuesday
echo date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(3)) . "\n"; // should be Wednesday
echo date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(4)) . "\n"; // should be Thursday
echo date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(5)) . "\n"; // should be Friday
```

Output:

```
Friday, April 5th
Monday, April 8th
Tuesday, April 9th
Wednesday, April 10th
Thursday, April 11th
Friday, April 12th
```

In your original code:

```
$dateStandardMinMG = date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(2));
$dateStandardMaxMG = date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(4));
$dateExpressMinMG = date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(0));
$dateExpressMaxMG = date("l, F jS", getDeliveryDay(1));
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am have been experimenting with this code. The challenge I am facing is that as you see in your example, instead of having getDeliveryDay(3), (4), and (5) return Tues, Wedn, and Thur, you get Mond, Mond, and Tues because the weekend. This is why I had additional code to account for that. I did update my original post to include all the html/php, so you could see exactly what is trying to be achieved. I think the post by Irish is close because it simply added on to what I already had so we don't have to worry about this dilemma, we just need to fix the +1 day issue.

Comment: Rather than pasting a bunch more code, I'd suggest laying out your requirements more concretely, as I did in the first sentence of my answer. What about that first sentence is incorrect? Answer that and things should make more sense.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what you're saying. Basically processing time shouldn't include weekends at all. Let me update code quickly.

Comment: Well it's updated, though I feel like it's quite inefficient running that for loop over every day. Part of me thinks there should be a better method, but I can't think of what it might be.

Comment: Thank you for this update, I am now able to get it to work. I hesitated to post more code, but thought it would help provide more context for Irish's response. I apologize for any confusion caused by my response. One last thing I wanted to ask was how to set the time to Pacific Time using your code, as it is off by 8 hours right now.

Comment: As in your original code, use `date_default_timezone_set("America/Los Angeles");` although your server should be configured correctly so you don't have to do this in all your code. Set `date.timezone` in php.ini.

Comment: After investigating, I realized the reason it had this issue was the timezone on the server was set to UTC. Fixing this solved this issue. Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to add +1 day to your calculation if the input time is past 2 PM? To keep it to your approach I would add a date format for the time and run through it like you did with the weekday

Since businessDays() calculates the delivery time I'd think it would fit right here

```
function businessDays($days, $time) {
    // Past 2 PM check should be outside the for loop
    $hours = date('G', $time);
    $weekend = date('w',$time);
    if ($hours > 14 AND $weekend != 0 AND $weekend !=6) {
        $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time); 
    }  
    for ($i=0; $i<$days; $i++) {
        $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
        $day = date('w',$time);
        if ($day==0) {
            $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
        } else if ($day==6) {
            $time = strtotime('+2 day', $time);
        }
    }
    return $time;
}
```

Comment: You have it exactly right. For the weekends, I would want it to be pushed to the following Monday (even more ideally, it would be able to account for federal US holidays and push to Tuesday, but I do not know if that is possible).

To make the code more clear, I added the rest of the code I previously omitted. Based on this, where should your code be placed? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer though I think miken32s answer is a lot more profound ;)

Comment: Your answer is great. I implemented it, and the delivery dates are all being pushed forward like I wanted. However, when I tried to confirm that your 2 PM cutoff was working by changing $hours > 14 to a larger value like 18 (right now its about 3:50 PM), the date is still being pushed to tomorrow instead of staying on today's date. Why would this be the case?

Comment: That's a good question...
I have tried it with various cut off times and manually input different $dateStart times (since it's 11 AM here ;) ) and it worked as expected. 
Try to echo the $dateStart variable, does it match your actual time?
And btw: it should be $hours >= 14 to ensure it's triggered at 2 PM (otherwise this would be only true at 3 PM and later), my mistake ;)

Comment: I went ahead and echoed the $dateStart variable, and it is pulling the correct time. Everything I've tried has no effect other than changing +1 day to now. Otherwise, the date is always being pushed forward to the next day no matter the time. For complete reference, I modified my original post to now include the html component, so you can see how the php is being implemented.

Comment: After I looked into this further, the issue was happening on my end as the server did not have the correct timezone setting. After this was corrected your code worked great. Thank you for helping with this code.